# VSCode python interpreter warning on built-in functions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode within a dev container but the python interpreter is raising warnings about undefined variables for built-in functions such as `len`, `range`, `str`, and `super`.

```
Undefined variable: 'range' Python(undefined-variable)
```

What could cause this? What other diagnostic information would be useful?
[image]

Edit: Added the version I am using.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use VS Code as well, and i have a similar issue `str is not defined - pylance`, according to internet, this issue appears when you set a variable with name `str`, or refer to a function/class before declaring it. However i do not have either of this situation.

In the end I navigated to "Extensions"-"Pylance" in VS Code, chose to "Switch to Pre-Release Version", then clicked "Reload Required". After reloading, this issue did not seem to appear. Then I switched back by clicking "Switch to Release Version", then reload again, the issue also does not seem to appear anymore. I think it's the reloading Pylance doing the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have have an [up-to-date copy of the Microsoft language server installed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3977) or consider using the beta version by setting `"python.analysis.downloadChannel": "beta"`. If that doesn't work then please report the bug to https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server with example code showing the problem.